# jquery plugin not working with scriptmanager

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I have used a jquery plugin (searchable dropdown). I have added following lines to masterpage, and it is working fine

```
<script src="Content/template/assets/js/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select").searchable();
        });
```

But I have added a script manager on one of the drop down, so plugin stopped working. how can I include jquery in script manager. Please help

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> <ContentTemplate> 
 <asp:DropDownList ID="txtArea" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="200px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Area" DataValueField="ID" TabIndex="9" AutoPostBack="True">
 </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleRightNowConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Area], [ID] FROM [Area] ORDER BY [Area]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
 </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You mean it's working if you remove the script manager from the page?

Comment: yes it is working without script manager